# AWS EMR: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, out-of-memory, amazon-emr

I have AWS EMR Spark job which has to process some 1.3 TB of data and I have read that HDFS replicates data size three times in the nodes. I am using 20 core nodes of m5.24xlarge (started trying from lower but did not succeed) with 768 GB EBS volume each. I am receiving the below error:

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 27571"...
```

For this, I have tried increasing the HADOOP_HEAPSIZE configuration to 2048 and then to 6144 but I am getting the same error after around 1 hour 30 minutes of the job run. I have tried several combinations of instance type, instance count, EBS volume and HADOOP_HEAPSIZE configuration but nothing seems to work here. I have read about this from the forum and AWS docs and applied the above changes. My SparkConfigurations are as below:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.memory", 10g);
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", 16g);
```

Any suggestion of how to achieve this? My program is simple and while doing spark.write.parquet (that is the last step of the job), the EMR step fails. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your code? This is needed to give you a proper answer :)

Comment: Sorry, the code is too huge infact the whole project. Just to confirm, it does work fine with 1.0 TB of data, but behaves this way with greater than that. Thanks.

Comment: Please at least show your spark config. How much memory does each executor get? How many executors are you using? Instance types don't matter if you're only using 2 executors, each with 1G of heap, for example. Also, EBS (not sure what you mean by EB2) has nothing to do with heap

Comment: Yeah sorry, EBS, EB2 was a typo. Can you please guide me how to get the values asked by you. While setting spark inside code, I'm not specifying anything so I assume it goes with defaults. Thanks

Comment: So i tried to set up executor and driver memory next as below but still no luck:

sparkConf.set("spark.driver.memory", 10g);
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", 16g);

Updating the question with this information too.